# Colorizing A Segmented Image

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation

I have segmented an image , and I now want my user to input colors as line segments onto the segments , and color the segment with the desired colors,,,how may I do it??
Thanks

Comment: short: what? long: please explain a bit - your question is not really understandable. A bit of code, a bit about the image, maybe what the inputs should be, how to color etc.

Comment: As in , suppose i have designed a gui , wherein i accept colors by click onto the pixels in a segmented and grayscale converted image , such that the entire region containing that pixel gets colored with the input color

Answer (score 0):

Using [ginput](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html)

```
[x,y,button] = ginput
```

you can get the coordinates of the click. Then you can paint using

```
image(x-R:x+R,y-R:y+R) = COLOR
```

I've presumed you have a 2D image matrix. For 3D, you'll have to [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [shiftdim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html) to make the  size of the color vector 1x1x3:

```
image(x-R:x+R,y-R:y+R,:) = repmat(shiftdim(COLOR,1),[2*N+1,2*N+1,1])
```

Again assuming you want to make a color square. A circle is a bit more complicated - probably a boolean mask is the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a grayscale or indexed image you can get the input coordinates with `ginput` as Dedek suggests and then modify the [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) for the index/grayscale value at those coordinates. You should also have a look at the `Colormap Editor` link at the bottom of the `colormap` link above to see if that meets your needs.